# Generic List Grouping + Sum Fields

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a generic list that looks like this:

```
ItemList
Item1 {Date:12/01/2017, Desc:ABC, Price:12.00, Number:12.00, Info:Bird}
Item2 {Date:12/01/2017, Desc:ABC, Price:10.00, Number:4.00, Info:Bat}
Item3 {Date:12/02/2017, Desc:ABC, Price:8.00, Number 3.00, Info:Cat}
```

I need to get the sum of Price and Number by date.
To something like this:

```
{Date:12/01/2017,Price:22.00,Number:16.00}
{Date:12/02/2017,Price:8.00,Number:3.00}
```

How can this be achieved in VB.NET?

Update1:
I have the grouping down.

```
Dim query = From itm In ItemList
            Group by Date = itm.Date
            Into DateGroup = Group, Sum(itm.Price)
```

I get the items to group and sum the price. Can I also get the sum of Number in that same statement?

Comment: You know grouping is involved, so have you tried anything?

Comment: [LINQ grouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx)

Comment: i grouped it just fine and got one of the sums i wanted, but can i sum `Number` in the same statement?